# how to determine a rational is square free?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, factorization

We know that if $μ(n)=0$ then the integer n has at least one factor with multiplicity.

Now how can we determine if in the decomposition of a rational (m/n)>1 to prime factors, we have a power less than (-1)? For example

```
m=2*3*5*7*11;

n=2^2*3^3*5;

m/n=2^(-1)*3^(-2)*7*11

f(m/n)=0 (*for example*)
```

Is there any function similar to Moebius function μ in Mathematica which does this job for me?
I think I can write the code, but I need a defined function in Mathematica?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it, 
It should be

```
f[x_]:=If[SquareFreeQ[x]==True,1,0]
```

Comment: If you just want a 0/1 answer, you could just do `Boole@SquareFreeQ@x` instead of the `If`